# yii2 how to view the logs of another .log file

Tags: yii2

I am using the yii2 framework with the 'queue' extension. This extension may fail, which is saved in the log file, and I would like to view the error in a specific view.
I was able to log errors into a specific .log file, so the real question is, how can I view errors from another log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii framework use category distinguish log file

config：

```
return [
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'timeZone' => 'PRC',
'components' => [
    'log' => [
        'targets' => [
            //default
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
            //especially
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
                'levels' => ['error'],
                'categories' => ['yii\db\*'],//The point 
                'logFile'=>'log.txt',//you custom file
            ],
            //especially2
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
                'levels' => ['error'],
                'categories' => ['app\models'],//The point 
                'logFile'=>'log.txt',//you custom file
            ],
            //especially3
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
                'levels' => ['error'],
                'categories' => ['abc'],//The point 
                'logFile'=>'log.txt',//you custom file
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

];

Use it

```
Yii::trace('db error');

Yii::trace('start calculating average revenue', __METHOD__);

Yii::trace('start calculating average revenue', 'abc');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
                'error' => 
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                    'categories' => ['yii\queue\Queue'],
                    'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/error.log',
                    //'enabled' => YII_DEBUG,
                    //'exportInterval' => 1,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).